# How to properly bind datacontext RelativeSource in WPF?

Tags: wpf, relativesource

I am defining the RelativeSource in my Template in the XAML, with

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I am getting an exception

> "A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception."

I think the problem is i need to bind this after my Window.Resources declarations but i am not sure how to do this using the `<DataContext` tags and still use RelativeSource. Thanks!

```
<Window x:Class="SupportDesk.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Top Echelon Support Desk" Height="554" Width="743" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" xmlns:myNewNamespace="clr-namespace:SupportDesk"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <myNewNamespace:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
  x:Key="GridBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
 Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
         AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
     Converter={StaticResource boolToVis},
         ConverterParameter=False}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I thin you are going to have to give more details. Can you provide a few snippets of code?

Comment: sure, here is my information in the xaml:

Comment: hmm, what would be the best way to post this?

Comment: just from researching online i think the reason the exception is occurring is because of the RelativeSource declaration is before my Window.Resources section. but every where i have looked the Relative source is always bound to specific elements, whereas i have three autocompleteboxes i am using from the WPF Toolkit, that reference this. i would like to delcare this using the datacontext tags but i dont think this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting the DataContext on the immediate child of your window? e.g.

```
<Window>
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: thanks for helping with this. the exception is gone when i do that however now no data is returning in my listview. basically i have three autocomplete boxes, and when a value is selected i run a query and return results in a listview. the data is no longer being returned

Comment: Time to do a bit of debugging! ... i you set a breakpoints, what is the DataContext for the listview? for the Grid? ...

Comment: Also ... why are you using a relative source self binding? Typically this is used for UI controls, not windows / forms.

Comment: i am not really sure. what should i be using?

Comment: well either way it was working until my recent problem which stemmed from my trying allow for editing a field in the listview. thanks for the suggestion, ill figure it out ...